# WriteToBigQuery with dynamic destinations

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working on an Apache Beam pipeline that reads a bunch of events from a pub/sub and then based on event type, it writes them into separate BigQuery tables.

I know that `WriteToBigQuery` supports dynamic destinations but the problem in my case is that the destination is derived from the data that is read from the event. For example:
an event looks like

```
{
 "object_id": 123,
 ... some metadata,
 "object_data": {object related info}
}
```

Data that should be written to BigQuery table is under the `object_data` key from the event, but, the table name is derived from other fields in the metadata.
I tried to use the side inputs params but the issue is that because each event can have different destinations, the side inputs don't update accordingly. The code is below:

```
class DumpToBigQuery(PTransform):

    def _choose_table(self, element, table_names):
        # table_names = {"table_name": "project_name.dataset.table_name}
        table_name = table_names["table_name"]
        return table_name

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        events = (
            pcoll
            | "GroupByObjectType" >> Map(lambda e: (e["object_type"], e))
            | "Window"
            >> WindowInto(
                windowfn=FixedWindows(self.window_interval_seconds)
            )
            | "GroupByKey" >> GroupByKey()
            | "KeepLastEventOnly" >> ParDo(WillTakeLatestEventForKey()
        )

        table_name = events | Map(lambda e: ["table_name", f"{self.project}:{self.dataset}.{e[0]}"])
        table_names_dct = AsDict(table_name)

        events_to_write = events | Map(lambda e: e[1]) | Map(self._drop_unwanted_fields)

        return events_to_write | "toBQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
            table=self._choose_table,
            table_side_inputs=(table_names_dct,),
            create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_NEVER,
        )
```

You can see that the side input is taken from the other branch of the pipeline `table_name` that is basically extracting the table name from the event. And then, this is given as input to `WriteToBigQuery`. Unfortunately, this doesn't really work as under load, the side input is not updated and some events are using wrong destinations.

What other approach I can use in this specific case? All the docs are using static examples and don't really cover this dynamic approach.

The other thing I tried is to write a custom `DoFn` that used the HTTP BigQuery client and inserts the rows, the issue here is the speed of the pipeline as is inserting around 6-7 events per seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, for which I have a work around.

I see that you have `create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER` so the list of tables is known before the code runs.  Perhaps it is unweildy, but it is known.  I have a `DoFn` which `yeild`s many `TaggedOutput`s its `process` method.  Then my pipeline looks like:

```
parser_outputs = ['my', 'list', 'of', 'tables']
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(), argv=args) as p:
    pipe = (
        p
        | "Start" >> beam.Create(["example row"])
        | "Split"
        >> beam.ParDo(MySplitFn()).with_outputs(*parser_outputs)
    )

    for output in parser_outputs:
        pipe[output] | "write {}".format(output) >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            bigquery.TableReference(
                projectId=options.projectId, datasetId=DATASET_ID, tableId=output
            ),
            schema=padl_shared.getBQSchema(parser.getSchemaForDataflow(rowTypeName=output)),
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        )

    p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: Does this scales well? I mean, I have around 23 tables in which the pipeline should write.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it and while it works, the main problem is that the step where it tags the value is very slow, with a throughput of around 6-7 elements/sec. Don't really understand why this step is so slow as it just does a small transform to the event and returns it with a tag.

Comment: My function that does the DoFn is quite complex.  It includes an object from an imported module, and the unit tests for the imported object are almost 1000 lines long (the object itself is a modest 200 lines plus a configuration file).  Still the I get 1000+ elements/sec on a single worker node.  If you [run your function locally in a test framework is it still slow](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/#testing-transforms)?

Comment: Locally is running ok and also, I am not able to simulate the load from the production environment. Also, I've noticed that I get this exception `apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.IntervalWindowCoderImpl.estimate_size: TypeError: Cannot convert GlobalWindow to apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase` that it only happens in production, not locally at all.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know what that error is about. I'm only using this pattern for batch, not for streaming.

Comment: The for loop used will cause an issue when the new workers are spawned due to autoscaling. Those new workers wont be able to maintain the state of the loop.