# WriteToBigQuery Dynamic table destinations returns wrong tableId

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to write to bigquery to different table destinations and I would like to create the tables dynamically if they don't exist already.

```
bigquery_rows | "Writing to Bigquery" >> WriteToBigQuery(lambda e: compute_table_name(e),
                                                schema=compute_table_schema,
                                                additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters,
                                                write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                )
```

The function compute_table_name is quite simple actually, I am just trying to get it to work.

```
def compute_table_name(element):
    if element['table'] == 'table_id':
        del element['table']
        return "project_id:dataset.table_id"
```

The schema is detected correctly and the table IS created and populated with records. The problem is, the table ID I get is something along the lines of:

```
datasetId: 'dataset'
projectId: 'project_id'
tableId: 'beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP...
```

I have also tried returning a bigquery.TableReference object in my compute_table_name function to no avail.

**EDIT**: I am using apache-beam 2.34.0 and I have opened an issue on JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13487)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my answer by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961309/15724334). It felt like a workaround because I'm not passing a callable to WriteToBigQuery(). Testing a bunch of ways I found that giving a string/TableReference to the method directly it worked, but not giving it a callable.

I process ~50 gigs of data every 15 minutes spread across 6 tables and it works decently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30812768)

Comment: It may be annoying, but I'm not sure I would call it a workaround: Apache Beam docs [actually specify](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) that if you are using a callable, you must return a `bigquery.TableReference` instead of just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You pipeline code is fine. However, you can just pass the callable to the compute_table name function:

```
bigquery_rows | "Writing to Bigquery" >> WriteToBigQuery(compute_table_name,
                                            schema=compute_table_schema,
                                            additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters,
                                            write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                            create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                            )
```

The `'beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP'` table name in BigQuery probably means that the load job either has not finished yet, or that it has errors ; you should check the "Personnal history" or "Project history" tabs in the BigQuery UI, to see what is the status of the job.

Comment: I have already tried your solution and it didn't work. When I checked the UI I could see that the table destination was incorrect as I declared in my post.